# How to read arrow notation to graph this polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials

How do you graph this polynomial function?

1. As $x \rightarrow -\infty$, $y\rightarrow -\infty$
2. As $x \rightarrow \infty$, $y \rightarrow -\infty$
3. Has a root at $x=4$

[Image of the Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24K2v.png)

Comment: I've re-edited the post.  I didn't see the other $-\infty$ in the first set of equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or $y = -(x-4)^2$ (or raised to any even power):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Condition 2 implies that the leading coefficient is negative. Condition 1 then implies that the degree is even. What is the simplest polynomial that satisfies all three conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Since the curve has a root $\ 4$, this means the curve cuts the x-axis at $\ (4,0)$. Now as $\ x\to \pm\infty$, $\ y\to -\infty$, this shows that      as you go along the x-axis (left and right direction), $\ y$ coordinates goes to the negative direction of $\ y$-axis.
So to sketch the graph, you just meet the graph to the $\ x$-axis at $\ (4,0)$ and extend its sides  towards the negative direction of $\ y$-axis. Try to plot $\ y=-\vert (x-4)\vert $
[image: get help here]